# Bvp4c with unknown boundary

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

I have a BVP describing the sagging of a catenary, where the right boundary is unknown (8 DE and 9 BC).
Does anybody know how to model this in Matlab with the function bvp4c?
Thank you.

Comment: the **B**oundary **V**alue **P**roblem solver `bvp4c` requires boundaries... you need a different solver.

Comment: I found a suggestion from LutzL [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42936333/bvp4c-solve-for-unknown-boundary] but I do not understand how to implement it in Matlab

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42936333/bvp4c-solve-for-unknown-boundary. Your question should contain a [mcve], more details about your equations/model, what you've tried, and some details which make it differ from the linked question.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot comment on that topic so I did not know how to ask for further information. I would just like to know how to implement in matlab the change in variable operated in fun1 in the Python code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same method as in the linked post applies, if you have a function `right_side(t,x)` and `boundary_conditions(xa,xb)` then you need wrapper functions that handle the additional component for the interval length,

```
function doty = wrapper_rhs(s,y)
  T = y(end)
  doty = T*right_side(t0+s*T, y(1:end-1))
  doty(end+1)=0
end
```

and

```
function bc = wrapper_bc(ya,yb)
  bc = boundary_conditions(ya(1:end-1), yb(1:end-1))
end
```

These should allow to call the BVP solver over the fixed interval ´[0,1]´.

Comment: thank you for your reply. could it be that `T = y(end)` should be the other way around?

Comment: No, it is the additional last component. It is trivial, a constant with derivative zero. But it needs to be a component so that the BVP solver can change it, a global variable will not be known and accessible to the solver. If you were to implement your own specific BVP solver you would not need the extra component, but a general purpose solver does not have the specific facilities.

Comment: what I meant was if the call should be written the other way around to have T as last element of the varaibles vector, i.e. `y(end) = T`.

Comment: No, `y` is the input, it is to be considered immutable. What is constructed is the derivative vector `doty` that is the output. `y(end)` contains the constant `T` that is set via the initial conditions. This setting of initial conditions is the only mechanism in the general BVP solver to change constant (along a specific solution) parameters.

Comment: dear @LutzL , with your approach, now I am facing a problem: my equations describe fluid being extruded and as such one boundary is constantly moving while at the other new fluid is continuously provided. I thought of representing the moving boundary as a collection of discrete time steps and to provide as initial guess for the current time, the solution from the previous iteration. My problem is how to include the freshly extruded fluid at the left boundary considering that, with your wrapping strategy, my simulating interval is always 1. thank you

Comment: This seems too complicated for the comments to discuss. This looks like it could descend into spaghetti code territory. It might be that you need to optimize for several variables at once, which might be done the same way, or might require more advanced solving/optimization methods. Please pose this general problem in the scientific computing forum http://scicomp.stackexchange.com as new question with sufficient background. You might use a simplified model or some other toy example if your original problem is too large or contains proprietary information.

Comment: dear @LutzL, is there any way you know to include the results (for example the temperature profile over the filament length) from a previous cycle in the current one? Where the cycles correspond to different ime points. Thank you again.

Comment: Do you want to solve delay-differential equations? Or the solution process of BVP? To include functions given as data series, use interpolation of the function table to make a continuous function, you can not predict which times the solver will access.

Comment: thank you for your reply. However, I think you did not get my point. As in IVP with ode45 where I can give initial conditions, I would like somehow to start the simulation for the temperature profile from the values from the previous iteration as it would happen by including explicit time dependency. thank you again.

Comment: I'm sorry, my imagination is not that good. I would need some formulas to be more specific. It still sounds like you need to interpolate a function table containing the values from a previous calculation. Sometimes it is better to extend the model so that the previous run and the current integration are done in the same call to ode45. That is, you have x'=f(t,x) and y'=g(t,x,y), then you can first integrate x and then pass the value table to the integration of y, or you integrate together [x', y'] = F(t,x,y) = [f(t,x), g(t,x,y) ].

Comment: shall I paste the equations here or send them to you in private? thank you again btw

Comment: You could also use something like pastebin. But for questions on the design of numerical algorithm you will find a larger qualified audience in http://scicomp.stackexchange.com. I'd suggest to post your question with the details, or the details of a sufficiently close mockup, there.