# Solve second order PDEs with `scipy.integrate`, with both initial and final position known

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations, odeint, pde

I'm confused reading `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp` [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html).

I'm interested in a ballistic problem with drag and Magnus effect, but I'm focussing first on the simpler problem, considering only gravitational force. The corresponding PDE is

[image: pde_second_order]

Transforming to a first order PDE, we can write

[image: pde_first_order]

I have the initial and final 3D positions and time of the ball [image: formula] for [image: formula], but I don't understand how to provide this information to the solver. It expects `y0` which, in my notations, is [image: formula], but I don't know the velocity at [image: formula]. (**note:** I know I can infer it from the second degree solution, but I don't want to since the solution will get very much more complex once I integrate the other forces).

How should the problem be transformed to add the other initial condition on the position [image: formula] ?

**note:** I also looked at the documentation of [solve_bvp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_bvp.html), but from my understanding, it doesn't fit the problem I try to solve…

Comment: Shouldn't velocity at T0 be a known value? In order to solve the Cauchy problem with a second order diff equation you need two boundary conditions, and in your case is x(0) and v(0)

Comment: V0 is not necessary for the simple parabola solution. v0 can be inferred from p0 (x,y,z), p1 (x,y,z), T0 and T1: `v0 = (p1 - p0)/(T1 - T0) - np.array([0], [0], [-g]])*(T1 - T0)/2)`

Comment: Different initial speeds lead to different trajectories, so it's needed, no?

Comment: You only have initial conditions, so there is nothing you infer later on when solving ODEs, at least in the pen and paper solutions.

Comment: with position at final time `T1`, initial velocity is not required (for the simple model where ball is only subject to gravity)

Comment: I'll wait someone more knowledgeable than me, but I believe these solvers are meant to solve a problem where you know the state dynamics and the state at T0. Since it is an iterative method, they need somewhere to start. What instead I think you are doing is expecting the solver to first find the general solution with C1 and C2 and fit C1 and C2 based on the constraints.

Comment: However, you can also try asking at https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `solve_bvp` is correct, you just need to map the variable time span to a fixed interval, where then the scale multiplicator is an extra parameter or component of the state vector. You get one extra boundary condition, so you could set the initial speed to a constant. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42936333/bvp4c-solve-for-unknown-boundary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `scipy.integrate.solve_bvp` is indeed appropriate, with `p0` and `p1`: (x(t), y(t), z(t)) at t=T0, T1. For posterity, here are the two functions required by `solve_bvp`:

```
def bc(X0, X1, args=None):
    x0, y0, z0, vx0, vy0, vz0 = X0
    x1, y1, z1, vx1, vy1, vz1 = X1

    return np.array([
        x0 - p0.x,
        y0 - p0.y,
        z0 - p0.z,
        x1 - p1.x,
        y1 - p1.y,
        z1 - p1.z,
    ])

def pde(t, X, args=None):
    x, y, z, vx, vy, vz = X
    dXdt = np.vstack([
        vx,
        vy,
        vz,
        np.ones_like(t)*0,
        np.ones_like(t)*0,
        np.ones_like(t)*g,
    ])
    return dXdt
```